# AJAX indicates that WEBMETHOD was successful, but it never actually triggers the webmethod on code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I've been through countless posts and cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I have a asp.net website with C# code behind. In it, I need for a javascript function on the .aspx page to trigger a method on the aspx.cs page. I wrote the following code:

.aspx page (my ScriptManager):

```
 </head>
 <body id="bodycontainer">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```

The Javascript function using ajax on the .aspx page:

```
  function ValidateForm() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/Save",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf=8",
            //  dataType: "json",  // NOT NEEDED IF NO RETURN VALUE
            async: true,  // OPTIONAL
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

The aspx.cs page (Code Behind page):

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void Save()
    {
      //  throw new DivideByZeroException(); // USED THIS TO VERIFY IF WEBMETHOD IS HIT.
        _default obj = new _default();
        obj.Show("Save Method Works"); // THIS IS A POPUP MESSAGE BOX
        obj.btnSave_Click(); // THIS IS THE SAVE METHOD ON THIS PAGE THAT WE WANT TO RUN
    }


 public void btnSave_Click()
 {
 // METHODS CODE HERE
 }
```

The ValidateForm function responds with "success", however, it doesn't seem like it is even triggering the WebMethod on the Code Behind page. If I use the I.E. Console Network tab, I can see the POST request. However, on the code behind method, it never triggers the breakpoints in debug (Not sure if it should according to some posts). At one point I inserted line to throw a DivideByZero exception and it never raised the exception.

So, to summarize, I get confirmation that he Javascript call to the WEBMETHOD worked by virtue of the success message and the POST message in the F12 Console Network tab. However, it doesn't seem that the WEBMETHOD ever fires.  Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to test an error instead of throwing an exception

```
Response.Clear();
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Response.End;
```

Comment: Thanks, It was already set for Active(Debug) and Active(Any CPU).  Even if it wasn't debugging and stopping at breakpoints, it still should have thrown and exception when I uncommented the line to throw a new Divide By Zero exception. No, I think its talking to the server like it should (hence the POST message in the Network tab). I think the server isn't running the webmethod for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did, but I think adding "UseHttpGet = false" allowed it to finally execute the webmethod.

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
    public static void Save()
    {
      //    throw new DivideByZeroException(); // USED THIS TO VERIFY IF WEBMETHOD IS HIT.
        _default obj = new _default();  // SINCE THIS METHOD IS STATIC, WE HAVE TO INSTANTIATE AND INSTANCE OF THE DEFAULT PAGE CLASS TO ACCESS METHODS ON THIS PAGE
        obj.Show("Save Method Works"); // THIS IS A POPUP MESSAGE BOX
        obj.btnSave_Click(); // THIS IS THE SAVE METHOD ON THIS PAGE THAT WE WANT TO RUN
    }


    function ValidateForm() {
        var text = "This is a Test";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf=8",
            data: "{}",
            url: "default.aspx/Save",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("status: " + textStatus);
                alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```